# file directory for saving .cpp & .h for the Arduino IDE for short #include statement

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I am trying to write a class/function that I think I will be using often in my Arduino IDE, I know the code but where should i save the file so that the IDE picks it up without a full directory address in the #include line, as you may guess I'm a little new to this....

Comment: You can make a header files and put it in the default search path for the compiler, or instruct the IDE to add your header-file path to the paths the compiler uses for header files. But that's only for header files. If you want source to go along with it, you should make a (static) library of your code, and put it in the linkers default search path, and tell your project to link with your library.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you will be reusing this code frequently, you might want to make a library as suggested by Joachim. Your library can then be added to any sketch you write using a `#include` statement.

The arduino website has a nice guide on writing libraries, check it out [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial).

If you would just like to include your header file in a sketch without writing a library, placing the header file in the same directory as your sketch should compile if you use `#include "header_file_name.h"`.